# Failed to load audio: [WinError 2] The specified file can not be found. RVC

Tags: python, ffmpeg, clone, text-to-speech, voice

Trying to convert audio with text to my own AI Model with rvc_convert, but it fails and got me this Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\python\py\tts\venv\src\rvc\lib\audio.py", line 14, in load_audio
    ffmpeg.input(file, threads=0)
  File "F:\Python\py\TTS\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "F:\Python\py\TTS\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\Quick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Quick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\py\TTS\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    rvc_convert(model_path='eduard.pth',
  File "f:\python\py\tts\venv\src\rvc-tts-pipe\rvc_infer.py", line 323, in rvc_convert
    wav_opt=vc_single(0,input_path,f0_up_key,None,f0method,file_index,file_index2,index_rate,filter_radius,resample_sr,rms_mix_rate,protect)
  File "f:\python\py\tts\venv\src\rvc-tts-pipe\rvc_infer.py", line 160, in vc_single
    audio = load_audio(input_audio_path, 16000)
  File "f:\python\py\tts\venv\src\rvc\lib\audio.py", line 19, in load_audio
    raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load audio: {e}")
RuntimeError: Failed to load audio: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

I read that other people had the same error. I need to do something with `ffmpeg`, but nothing works for me.
Python 3.10

Tried to reinstall ffmpeg. Not working.
Trying to use other Python versions. Not working.
Trying to extract ffmpeg.exe from this archive https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases into ffmpge library folder. Not working

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed that by replacing code in audio.py with code from this [link](https://github.com/JarodMica/tts-pipeline-example/issues/2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).